# How to access Neo4j using Orange data mining tool?

Tags: python, neo4j, orange

I was not able to find sufficient information in the documentation or code examples which I can follow for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Orange Data mining tool does not have a direct Neo4j connector. I looked around the documentation a bit and you can use a CSV file as an input. You can export the CSV file from Neo4j either in your favorite scripting language or you can use [APOC plugin](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/export/csv/) to export CSVs.I saw that there exists a SQL connector. If you can find the JDBC connector for Orange Data mining there exists https://neo4j.com/bi-connector/.

Answer (score 0):

**Orange Data Mining tool, CSV loading and saving data**

https://orange-data-mining-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/data.io.html#loading-and-saving-data-io

**Neo4j, Export to CSV**

https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/export/csv/

**Python**

`import csv` - https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv

`import json` - https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json